# When should you push variables in quotes in boolean conditions?

Tags: bash

Are the following two boolean expressions the same?

```
if [ -n $1 ] ; then

if [ -n "$1" ] ; then
```

If not - When should you put a variable in quotes?

Comment: While this is not strictly off-topic, it could get more attention at Stack Overflow, or possibly [unix.se].

Comment: Thanks - I posted this question on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202778/when-should-you-push-variables-in-quotes-in-boolean-conditions and would like to request that this question gets deleted from askubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that should demonstrate the difference

```
~$ t="alfa beta"
~$ if [ -n $t ] ; then echo OK ; fi 
 bash: [: alfa: binary operator expected
~$ if [ -n "$t" ] ; then echo OK ; fi 
 OK
~$ ls blah*
blah1 blah2 blah3
~$ t="blah*"
~$ if [ -n "$t" ] ; then echo OK ; fi 
 OK
~$ if [ -n $t ] ; then echo OK ; fi
bash: [: too many arguments
```

In other words, with quotes, the `$t` is expanded only once and put in quotes as a single argument to `test` (`[` is just an alias to `test`). Without quotes, it is substituted by the contents of `$t` and then *expanded again*.

Answer (score 0):

In the `test` conditions, which is the same as `[`, you should always use double quotes, otherwise the `test` command might miss an argument if the variable is empty or undefined, or have too many arguments if the variable contains whitespace. In `bash`, though, it is safer to use the builtin `[[` for conditions that does not need the quotes.